# getElementsByTagName('a'); not working?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

So I do this:

```
var stuff = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
```

Works fine. Then I want to do this:

```
var other = stuff.getElementsByTagName('a');
```

but it doesn't work. It ends up being undefined. I can do:

```
var other = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
```

and it's fine. Should I not be able to get all the 'a' in 'iframe'?

Edit: So I don't own the iframe and am now under the impression that I can't access anything the iframe generates which meansI guess I'm screwed.

Comment: @Anurag No. I saw someone posted an answer saying you can't access that information due to browser security but they deleted it. I guess you can only access the actual iframe part and any content it generates is off limits?

Answer (score 10):

Use..

```
var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0],
    iframeDoc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
```

[Specification](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-iframe-element.html#dom-iframe-contentdocument).

Then, you can call `getElementsByTagName('a')` on `iframeDoc`. Alternatively, you could access `iframeDoc.links`, which isn't quite the same but may be what you want.

Of course, this all relies on the access to the `iframe`'s `document` not violating [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: This is correct. getElementsByTagName is a method on a document, not on a link. The way you are trying to do it, you (townie) are trying to do it is sort the children of a tag.

Comment: Given that `iframe.contentDocument` doesn't work in IE<8 I'd opt for only using the `iframe.contentWindow.document` which works reliably cross-browser. There's no benefit in first attempting to use contentDocument - only the code will be longer.

Comment: @ReneSaarsoo Yeah, I thought maybe the second was IE's propriety way of doing business, but the spec mentions both. I'll fix it :)

Answer (score 4):

[`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) returns a NodeList, which you'll need to iterate over. To iterate over it, you can do:

```
for (var i = 0; i < stuff.length; i++) {   
    var other = stuff[i].getElementsByTagName('a');
}
```

However, `getElementsByTagName('a')` asks for children inside the current document, which is almost certainly not what you want. If you want children inside the document in the frame, you'll need to do:

```
for (var i = 0; i < stuff.length; i++) {   
    var other = stuff[i].contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('a');
}
```

This will work if you have multiple iframes, and in older versions of IE.

Comment: It's not actually an array.  It's a node list.

Answer (score 3):

```
stuff[0].contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('a')
```

should produce an array-like object containing all the links in the zero-th iframe.

You need to use `contentWindow.document` because the `<iframe>` does not contain any nodes in the current document -- it is a frame whose `contentWindow` property points to a different window with its own document.

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByTagName` returns an array of matching elements. To access an individual IFRAME, you would use `stuff[0]` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Why is everyone suggesting `contentWindow.document` when you can just use `contentDocument` instead?

Of course, both work, but I prefer to use what I mean. If I want the window, I use `contentWindow`. If I want the document, I use `contentDocument`.